# Jacobian and chain rule

Tags: matrix-calculus, jacobian

I am trying to work out the derivative of a scaler ($J$) with respect to a vector ($x$) via chain rule. Below I laid out the steps in between, I find the matrix shape only checks out when I consider $x$ is a row vector. I labeled the details as below.

Red is the shape of a vector, and blue is the shape of the derivative matrix.

[image]

I think I still don't understand Jacobian, or derivative of a vector w.s.t. a vector well enough, please correct me.

**Answer**: the RHS of the second equation should be transposed since the left hand has been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the RHS of your expressions they are identical, however, the LHS you have affected by transposition. When you transpose a vector
$$
z=Ax
$$
then the transpose is
$$
z^T=(Ax)^T=x^TA^T.
$$
Correspondingly, the RHS must change.

P.S. The first line is better for understanding and more natural, the second line is a burden from the vector analysis to have the gradient to be a vector instead of a row.

Comment: I thought normal people prefer column vectors (influenced by [Gilbert Strang's MIT linear algebra](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/) course and my own reading in general, but when it comes to Jacobian, it's actually row vectors are prefered, which is why Jacobian equation on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) used row vector, is that correct?

Comment: Linear algebra calculations prefer column vectors, that's why gradients tend to be a column. However, the gradient/Jacobian are [covariant transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors). It is a conflict that is hard to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Just uploaded a version that illustrate the right way to look at the chain rule with proper transpose operations. Convention: $x$ is a column-vector, $x^T$ is its corresponding row vector.

[image]